# How to extract columns with alphabetic characters to data in list form

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[this is my csv example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbpHQ.png)I'm studying machine learning. For a good study, columns with string data should be separated by a list of only the names of the columns and replaced by a different format. If you have an English character for all the data in each column, and if you have an English character, I want to add the column to the list and work on it later.

So I tried to double-for-word the total_alphabet list with the column names of my data and the ALL1_columnns list with the column names of my data, but failed.

```
import model
import preprocess as pre
import pandas as pd
import string

X,Y,ALL = pre.getTrainDataEX('report .csv')
print('Origin_Data',X.shape,Y.shape,ALL.shape)

ALL1 = ALL.dropna(axis=1)
X1 = X.dropna(axis=1)

print('DropNa_Data',X1.shape,ALL1.shape)

lower_alphabet = map(chr,range(97,123))
upper_alphabet = map(chr,range(65,91))

total_alphabet = lower_alphabet + upper_alphabet

ALL1_columns=list(ALL1.columns)
col_list = []

for i in ALL1_columns:
    for j in total_alphabet:
        if j in ALL1[i]:
            col_list.append(ALL1_columns[i])

print col_list
```

Variable i has column names of ALL1. So the print(i) prints out the column names of ALL1. And j specifies each letter. ALL1[i] outputs data in i column. There was no error, but nothing was added to the col_list.

this is the dataframe:

```
info.score info.category info.git.head info.git.fetch_head
2.8        file           13cbed0d9    13cbed0d9
```

Comment: Could you provide us a row example of the columns how your data looks like?

Comment: @PV8 i try to add my csv.

Comment: always try to add it without an image :) this is easier for the community

Comment: 1. Since you imported the `string` module, you should replace all the lines about total_alphabet to : `string.ascii_letters` -- 2. To me, it is unclear what you are asking and you should try to provide a [mcve]. Meaning, input/your_code/desired output you cannot achieve.

Comment: @IMCoins i want to get list. My csv data has several features. Most are columns with only numeric data, but some have English-only or English-numeric data. I'd like to find a column with a little bit of English data.

Comment: @IMCoins What I ultimately want is to find out if each column of the csv has an English sentence, and if I have it, extract the column separately, even by name.